# TRIM support on an USB-attached SSD

Tags: linux, usb, ssd, lvm, trim

I have an SSD (Samsung 860 EVO) attached via an USB-SATA adapter (I tried both [this one](https://www.ebay.fr/itm/USB-3-0-To-Sata-2-5-C%C3%A2ble-Adaptateur-lecteur-de-disque-dur-externe-HDD-disque/202678888631?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649) and [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B011M8YACM)) to an ARM computer ([Odroid N2](https://www.hardkernel.com/shop/odroid-n2-with-4gbyte-ram/)) running Armbian (Linux 4.9.180).

I partitionned it with LVM (simple setup: a single PV, VG, and LV; no encryption). But when I mount it, I get this warning in dmesg:

```
[87990.092895] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounting with "discard" option, but the device does not support discard
```

and fstrim fails:

```
# fstrim /var/lib/postgresql 
fstrim: /var/lib/postgresql: the discard operation is not supported
```

---

I checked, and hdpart indicates that the hardware should support TRIM:

```
# hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep TRIM
       *    Data Set Management TRIM supported (limit 8 blocks)
       *    Deterministic read ZEROs after TRIM
```

lsusb and dmesg confirm this is an UAS/SCSI device:

```
# lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci-hcd/1p, 5000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 5000M
# dmesg
[...]
[87893.325796] scsi host0: uas
[87893.337014] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Samsung  SSD 860 EVO 500G 3202 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[87893.394341] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[87893.394928] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
[87893.394938] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
[87893.395718] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[87893.395729] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 53 00 00 08
[87893.396153] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Disabling FUA
[87893.396163] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[87893.396322] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.0.auto: ERROR Transfer event for disabled endpoint or incorrect stream ring
[87893.396331] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.0.auto: @00000000cf6128b0 00000000 00000000 1b000000 03078001
[87893.396593] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (4096 bytes)
[87893.401435]  sda: sda1
[87893.404218] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[87990.092895] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounting with "discard" option, but the device does not support discard
[87990.092901] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: discard
```

But lsblk indicates the device does not support DISCARD/TRIM (["in DISC-GRAN and DISC-MAX [...] non-zero values indicate TRIM support"](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSD#TRIM)):

```
# lsblk --discard
NAME             DISC-ALN DISC-GRAN DISC-MAX DISC-ZERO
sda                     0        0B       0B         0
`-sda1                  0        0B       0B         0
  `-vg0-pg_data0        0        0B       0B         0
```

Edit: I tried connecting the disk+adapter to a different computer; results are the same (except there are no errors in dmesg)

---

What should I do to enable support for TRIM/DISCARD/fstrim?

Comment: This is likely some of the problem “ERROR Transfer event for disabled endpoint or incorrect stream ring”

Comment: I just tried with a different computer. This error does not appear, but I still can't use fstrim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not manage to make these particular adapters pass TRIM commands, but I did find a solution.

First you need an adapter using a JMicron JMS578 chip. I found two: [hardkernel's Bridge Board Plus](https://www.hardkernel.com/shop/usb3-0-to-sata-bridge-board-plus/) (you need the "Plus" one), or [this one I found on amazon](https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B07JGRDWK1/).

I only tried the latter (cheaper and quicker for me to get), but [odroid's forum reports the same procedure works for the former](https://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?f=95&t=28241).

You must then upgrade the firmware of the JMS578 (these instructions only work for an armhf system, though it may work with an emulator):

```
wget https://wiki.odroid.com/_media/odroid-xu4/software/jms578fwupdater.tgz
tar xzf jms578fwupdater.tgz
cd jms578fwupdater
./JMS578FwUpdate -d /dev/sda -f ./JMS578-Hardkenel-Release-v173.01.00.02-20190306.bin -b ./backup.bin
```

[Hardkernel's wiki page](https://wiki.odroid.com/odroid-xu4/software/jms578_fw_update) gives more details about how to use it, and other features.

Comment: Seems like a good answer to me; you can accept your own answers after 2 days. Yes, the controller chip matters.